# Multiple selection in image crop plugin

Tags: jquery, image, jcrop

Is there any image crop plugin where we can select area simultaneously.I have used JCrop plugin
    http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

But ,in this we can use only 1 area at a time.
Any help will be appreciable .

Comment: is it not a research kind of question?
And why my rating got demoted ?

Comment: did you find any solution I am looking for the similar solution too!